# How do I determine if elements of a list within a cell on a pandas dataframe are identical

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe in which one column contains lists.  I want to find out which lists contain duplicates, and would like the list containing duplicates to be indicated as such on a helper column.

I tried to cycle through each list.  I then tried to compare the result with the first element of the list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'List': [['22', '65'], ['22', '22'], ['22', '91']],
})

df['Multiples'] = df['List'].apply(lambda x: any(i == x[0] for i in x))

print(df)
```

I expected the second row to return True; I also expected the first and third row to return False.  Instead, everything returned True.

Edit: I should have used 'all' rather than 'any' because 'any' returns true when the first element is compared to itself.  But it doesn't work for the following scenario because the middle section should still return true:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'List': [['22', '65'], ['22', '22','34'], ['22', '91']],
})

df['Multiples'] = df['List'].apply(lambda x: all(i == x[0] for i in x))

print(df)
```

Comment: Using a `set` is a common way to test for this e.g. `len(x) > 1 and (len(x) != len(set(x)))` - Although depending on what you're doing exactly, you could reshape your data with an `.explode` e.g. `df_flat = df.explode("List").reset_index(); df_flat.duplicated()`

Comment: df['Multiples'] = df['List'].apply(lambda x: len(x) > 1 and (len(x) != len(set(x)))) works brilliant.  If you put it as an answer I'll vote it up.

Comment: Additional tip for anyone who created a dataframe with entries containing a list: exporting it to .csv will change the list type to string type and @jqurious's solution won't work.

Comment: Are you saying you need a way to do this for a string repr of a list too?

Comment: How kind of you to ask, thanks. Answer: no need for an additional solution, I solved my problem by not exporting to csv.  Also, in the end I used explode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a `set` to de-dup:

```
df['Multiples'] = df.List.apply(lambda x: len(x) > len(set(x)))
```